# Android - Activity Typecasting into an Interface Type

Tags: android

This is code from Head First Android. Inside onAttach method, I'm wondering how the Activity activity variable is being typecast into WorkoutListListener. Is there a super-sub relationship?

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {

public WorkoutListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

static interface WorkoutListListener {
    void itemClicked(long id);
}

private WorkoutListListener listener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String[] names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Workout.workouts.length; i++) {
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.itemClicked(id);
    }

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.listener = (WorkoutListListener) activity;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all that's a risky approach. The safest solution would be:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(context);
if(activity instanceof WorkoutListListener) {
    this.listener = (WorkoutListListener) activity;
}
```

}

Now what you see here is a common patter of observer that is used in android. 
If an activity is managing some fragments and wants to observe some events from the fragments and perform actions based on that, the activity will implement a predefined `interface`, the same interface that is used for casting in `onAttach`.

So, in your example, the activity that handles the display of the fragment will have to implement `WorkoutListListener` interface.

Worst case scenario `WorkoutListListener` is an Activity, which is a really bad name for an activity :)), then all the Activities that handles the fragment will have to subclass `WorkoutListListener`. (but the second option is ugly).

Comment: you mean the activities must extend WorkoutListListener right?

Comment: @KevinBaik, Technically, ```WorkoutListListener``` should be an interface so, the activities have to implement the interface, if ```WorkoutListListener``` it's a subclass of ```Activity``` then yes, all the activities have to extend ```WorkoutListListener```.

Comment: @KevinBaik I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

`onAttach` expects an activity reference of type `Activity`. That is the generic activity type of Android. However, a custom activity (such as the one in the example) may implement some interface. So, we need to cast the `Activity activity` reference to our custom activity type, or just cast to the interface type for the sake of the assignment (such as in the posted code).

Comment: If the activity passed in does not implement the interface, will that typecasting result in an error?

Comment: Yes, this fragment can only be a child of WorkoutListListener

Comment: The type casting won't result in a compilation error. However, a class cast exception will be thrown if an interface method is called on the wrongly casted instance.